# htaccess - replace part of url

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I have a site and i wish to replace a part of URL, `https://example.com/[THISPART]/file.ext`.

Example URLs that will be requested on site:

```
https://example.com/example-page/sw.js
https://example.com/example-page/image.jpg
https://example.com/some-other-page/sw.js
https://example.com/some-other-page/file.pdf
https://example.com/page-with-attitude-4/sw.js
https://example.com/page-with-attitude-4/info.txt
```

How I want to rewrite them:

```
https://example.com/content/example-page/sw.js
https://example.com/example-page/image.jpg
https://example.com/content/some-other-page/sw.js
https://example.com/some-other-page/file.pdf
https://example.com/content/page-with-attitude-4/sw.js
https://example.com/page-with-attitude-4/info.txt
```

In other words, if only sw.js is requested, then rewrite to other URL.
What I have used so far in my htaccess is this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/sw.js$ content/$1/sw.js [L]
```

I've been using http://htaccess.mwl.be/ as a tester and test shows alright, but when I use it on site, it doesn't work. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Made it!

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z-]+)/sw\.js$ /places/$1/sw.js [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Crucially, the modified `RewriteRule` _pattern_ (ie. `([A-Za-z-]+)`) matches just a single path segment, so prevents a rewrite loop. (The `QSA` flag is not required here - the query string is appended by default.)

Comment: @MrWhite, found out the same. Always these thing that you don't work with everyday steal the most time in a project :) After reading regex documentation, trial and error for few hours - came to the same conclusion. Since I was using that webiste for testing and it showed no error, thought my first Rewrite rule was correct. Now I know that website is not all-that-good. Anyways, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Put the folowing code at your main directory `.htaccess` file :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} sw\.js 

#the line above to match sw.js

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !content

# the line above to exclude any request including content from the following rule

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ content/$1 [R=302,L,NE]

#the line above to apply redirection for requests that passed previous conditions and redirect any request ended with sw.js 

RewriteRule ^content/(.*)$ /$1 [L,QSA]

#the last line is to make internal redirection for original path
```

After testing , if it is Ok , change `302` to `301` if you wanna make permanent redirection

Comment: Since I made it with just RewriteRule earlier, I'll keep that for now, but thanks a lot! :)